# Dropdown and input search box. Not searching database and pulling 0 results

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hoping you guys can help. I am creating a search bar that allows the user to select the field they want to search under as well typing the search term. However, it seems that when they search it will produce the "No records found". Could anyone take a look at my code and see where I might of gone wrong? Thank you so much!

HTML Form

```html
<form name="search" method="post" action='recordresult.php' class="form-style-1">
    Search for: <input type="text" name="find" /> in

    <Select NAME="field">
        <Option VALUE="first_name">First Name</option>
        <Option VALUE="surname">Surname</option>
        <Option VALUE="address">Address</option>
        <Option VALUE="phonenumber">Phone Number</option>
    </Select>
    <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Php

```html
<?php
include("config.php");
$link = mysqli_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass) or die ("Could not connect to mysql because ".mysqli_error($link));

// select the database
mysqli_select_db($link, $database)
    or die ("Could not select database because ".mysqli_error($link));

//get information
$field = $_POST['field'] ;
$find = $_POST['find'] ;
$searching = $_POST['searching'] ;

//once submitted  
if ($searching =="yes") { 
    echo "<h2>Results</h2><p>"; 
 
    //search database 
    $data = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE $field LIKE'%$find%'"); 
 
    //display the results 
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array( $data )) { 
        echo "<div class='result'><b>";
        echo $result['first_name']; 
        echo "</b><br/>"; 
        echo $result['surname']; 
        echo "<br/>"; 
        echo $result['address']; 
        echo "<br/>"; 
        echo $result['phonenumber']; 
        echo "<br/>"; 
        echo "</div>"; 
    } 
 
    //number of results or error 
    $anymatches=mysqli_num_rows($data); 
    if ($anymatches == 0) { 
        echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query<br><br>"; 
    } 
 
    //the search term 
    echo "<br><b>Searched For:</b> " .$find; 
} 
?>
```

Tried having '' on the query around the field name variable also has the same result. Checked the variable for the field name and it is producing the right field in there.

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ to SQL Injections. Use Prepared Statements instead of using the user data directly in the query like that.

Comment: You should also create a white list of allowed columns since you can't use Prepared Statements for column names.

Comment: If  `$find = "test%'; DROP TABLE characters; --"` I'm sure you can have some surprise ! And you should make a pre-select list according to the field selected for the "search for:" to avoid syntax error, no?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST)` and see if it contains what you think. You should also add some error handling for the query as well: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php. Right now, there are too many unknowns for us to know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In some case try using "." for query.

```
$data = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM characters WHERE $field LIKE '%".$find."%'");
```